# C++ Blackjack Function

Tags: c++, blackjack

I've started teaching myself C++ and have been trying to write a blackjack program.  I'm trying to use classes to represent the cards, deck, and hands.  I believe everything is working in the program so far except the `dealCardToHand()` method.

```
void dealCardToHand(deck& d, hand& h){
    h.setCard(h.getCardsInHand(), d.dealCard());
    h.setCardsInHand(h.getCardsInHand() + 1);
}
```

It seems to correctly increment the number of cards in the hand but does not call the `setCard()` method with the correct data. Any help would be appreciated. I'm including the relevant classes and methods:

```
class deck{
    int topCard;
    card * cards[52];
 public:
     deck();
     void shuffle();
     void printDeck();
     card dealCard();
};

card deck::dealCard(){//returns top card of deck and increments top card one
    return *cards[topCard++];
}

class hand{
    card * handCards[12];
    int cardsInHand;
public:
    hand();
    card getCard(int i){ return *handCards[i]; }
    void setCard(int i, card c) { handCards[i] = &c; }
    int getCardsInHand() { return cardsInHand; }
    void setCardsInHand(int i) { cardsInHand = i; }
    void printHand();
};
```

Comment: STL containers would make your life a lot easier. There's also a `std::random_shuffle` algorithm, should that float your boat.

Answer (score 4):

This is dangerous (and probably at least part of your problem):

```
void setCard(int i, card c) {handCards[i]=&c;}
```

Here, `setCard(...)` is passed a `card` object by value.  This means that a new copy of the caller's `card` is created in temporary location.  It is this copy (`c`) which `setCard()` acts on.  By setting `handCards[i]=&c;`, you save the location of this temporary object.  But when `setCard()` returns, that temporary object is no longer valid.

But then you go on to dereference `handCards[i]` in `getCard()`.  This yields undefined behavior.  In theory, you should expect demons to start flying out of your nose.  In practice, you will see total garbage returned from `getCard()`.  Or a crash.  Or maybe, if you're sufficiently unlucky, the last value passed into `setCard()`.

On the whole, it looks like you're playing fast and loose with pointers.  I'd suggest one of two ways to resolve the problem:

1. Use pointers everywhere, never pass or return by value.  This will probably lead to other issues, but they might not be quite so mysterious.
2. Use pointers nowhere.  Pass and return everything by value.

Of course those aren't the only options, but they might make your life easier for the time being.

Comment: @chris: mostly agree.  If the idea is to learn C++, though...  well, it's said "The burned hand teaches best." -- Tolkien (?)

Comment: Surely a good book would have better examples for practising with pointers than pointlessly using them in a project where they're simply not needed, though.

Comment: @Managu are you saying to purposely give bad advice so the asker will learn the hard way? That is more likely to result in giving up on C++ than giving up on pointers. And giving up on pointers would also be bad, they still have uses although they are never the first alternative.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Not really.  From a modelling perspective, it makes sense to have a single `card` object for every card in the deck, and change the card's owner when the card is dealt out.  Maybe more sense than printing up a new card identical to the deck's top card, giving the copy to the player, and then shredding the original card.  It's not absurd to use pointers to model this scenario, particularly if c++11 is not on the table.  Indeed, one might do something like this in practice under different circumstances.

Comment: @Managu There is no apparent reason to use pointers in this program, and the best practice would therefore be to avoid them. "Not absurd" isn't a good standard to live by.

Comment: Understanding how pointers work is important in C++.  As is the experience that using pointers well can be hard enough to warrant rethinking one's design.  That's what I was really after with the comment 'the burned hand teaches best.'  Certainly there are other alternatives, in this case.  But if the idea is learn about C++, toy problems are a good place IMHO to poke at some of the more complex issues.

Comment: @Managu No matter what he does, he'll learn something. He'll learn more, faster, by finding the right solution to the problem. Perhaps the next problem will call for pointers, but trying to gratuitously use every solution pattern will won't teach anything *well.*

Comment: Maybe more to the point, *removing* pointers from a program is just as essential and commonly-used a skill as correctly putting them in place. So the suggestion to take them out and replace with containers sill implies learning something more about pointers.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I basically agree with your idea of the most reasonable design for the problem at hand.  Are you saying that I'm out of line when I suggest that other approaches might be instructive?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12833/discussion-between-managu-and-potatoswatter)

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  I agree that it makes more sense to have the deck and hand contain actual card objects rather than pointers to them.  I didn't intend to have it structured this way but when I started I was getting errors when I tried to declare class Deck{ card cards[52]; .... so I was thinking that it might have been that I could not have other classes in my deck class and only pointers to them.  Is this correct or should I be able to have actual card objects in my deck and the errors were caused by something else?  If so I'll probably go back and try to rework the code

Comment: So I've done some research and the reason I can't do this is because I need to initialize the cards using an initializer list.  [source](http://python.cs.southern.edu/cppbook/html/ch16s03.html) The only problem is I was using a couple nested for loops to loop through the deck and create one of every card which I don't think I can do in the initializer list.  Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: yup.  `#include <vector>`.  Then use a `std::vector<card>` instead of an array.  It'll start empty, but you can run your for-loop and at each iteration `push_back(...)` the next card.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the issue is that you're storing the address of a temporary variable in a pointer variable and dereference that pointer variable after the temporary has gone out of scope (and has been deleted).

Allow my answer to move a bit more into the abstract:

In C++, we distinguish between value classes and polymorphic classes. You will find them under different names, and you will also find classes where the distinction between the two is not as sharp as one would like, but it roughly goes like this:

1. Value class instances differ from each other in their state. If the state of two instances is equal, the behaviour of the instances will be equal, too.

   Examples of value classes are `std::string`, all STL containers, `std::complex<>`, etc.

   You use them as you would use `int`s: you create them on the stack:

   ```
   std::string s = "Hello, World"; // NOT std::string * s = new std::string;
   ```

   aggregate them by value:

   ```
   class Widget {
       std::complex<double> m_value; // NOT std::complex<double> * m_value;
   public:
       // ...
   };
   ```

   you can usually compare them for equality, copy them around, store them in 
   containers:

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
   std::string s = "Hello, World";
   assert( s == "Hello, World" );
   vec.push_back( s );
   ```

   and, most relevant to your question, you pass them around by (const-)reference (or by value, esp. if they're very small), and you return them by value, too:

   ```
   void func(const std::vector<double> & vec); // ok, just reading 'vec'
   void func(std::vector<double> & vec); // ok, possibly writing to 'vec'
   void func(std::vector<double> vec); // not so good, expensive in C++03; ok in C++11 in some situations
   std::vector<double> func(); // ok, return value optimisation (look it up!) will make this fast
   ```
2. Polymorphic classes differ in behaviour, not state. Two instances of a polymorphic class may have the same state, yet still behave completely different. Polymorphic classes *may* also differ in their state, but the focus is on their behaviour. This is what OOP (object-oriented programming) is all about.

   Borrowing example classes from the well-known C++ library "Qt", a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton` are both `QWidget`s. They may have the same state (size, position, ...), yet what happens when you click into each with the mouse is completely different between them.

   In C++, to use polymorphic behaviour, you must call *virtual* functions, and you must do so through a pointer or reference to a common base class (`QWidget` in the above). Therefore, polymorphic classes are usually allocated on the heap:

   ```
   QLineEdit * le = new QLineEdit();
   QPushButton * pb = new QPushButton();

   QWidget * leAsWidget = le; // works
   QWidget * pbAsWidget = pb; // works
   ```

   and stored and passed around in (smart) pointer variables:

   ```
   class MyWidget : public QWidget {
       QLineEdit * m_lineEdit;
       QPointer<QPushButton> m_pushButton; // QPointer is a smart pointer
   public:
       // ...
   };
   ```

For your program, you have to decide whether you need `deck` and `hand` to be polymorphic or not.

If yes, create them on the heap (with `new`), store and pass them around by pointer, and don't forget to delete them again when you're done with them (or have a look at smart pointer).

If no, give them relational operators (`bool operator==(const deck &lhs, const deck &rhs)`, ...), copy semantics (`deck(const deck&)`, `deck &operator=(const deck&)`), create them on the stack and store them by value. Pass them around by (const) reference. You don't need to delete them, the compiler will do that for you.